# Best way to use skip logic on Access Form?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am experimenting with skip logic on a MS Access form and wanted advice on the best controls to put in place. Surprisingly, I did not find threads here pertaining to this.

So, background: Using MS Access 2013 to build a simple form for a user questionnaire. We do not allow blanks on our form and have a module that checks for blanks and will not let user proceed to next section until all required fields are filled in. Instead we ask the user to input "-99" if they absolutely cannot answer the question.

The skip logic I am writing states that if answers to Q1 and Q2 are both no=0, then they have the option of skipping the next few questions. I wrote in the option with a y/n MsgBox that pops up after Q2 is answered. See my code below. The issue is that I can already foresee problems with the event I have chosen. What if they answer yes to Q1, no to Q2 (no pop-up) then go back and change their answer to Q1. I have tab order on my form, but that does not prevent the user from skipping around if they want to.

So my question in a nutshell, what is the best way to implement skip logic that depends on the answers from two fields?

```
Private Sub Q2_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo Error_Trap

If (IsNull(Me.CSSRSsi1) Or IsNull(Me.CSSRSsi1)) Then
Exit Sub
Else:

If (Me.Q1 = 0 And Me.Q2 = 0) Then

If MsgBox("Answers to Question 1 and 2 are both 'No'" & vbNewLine _
    & "Proceed to Q5?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
    DoCmd.GoToControl "Q3"
Else:
Me.Q3 = -99
Me.Q4 = -99
DoCmd.GoToControl "Q5"
End If

End If
End If

Q2_Exit:
Exit Sub

Error_Trap:
MsgBox Error$
Resume Q2_Exit

End Sub
```

UPDATE: AS Remou led me, I added a checker to Q1 and Q2 to make sure they have both been answered before proceeding to my skip logic code. And this is called AfterUpdate for both Q1 AND Q2.

Comment: Have you considered a procedure that is called when either q1 or q2 is updated?

Comment: Tell me more of what you are thinking. I don't want the MsgBx that gives them the option to skip ahead to pop up multiple times, it should only be triggered after both Q's are filled in... which actually makes me think I could add code to CHECK that both Q1 and Q2 are filled before the MsgBox opens. Let me try that...

Comment: Exactly, use a routine with several IFs that can be called when either or the questions are updated.

Comment: Thanks Remou, See updated code above. How do you feel about the AfterUpdate event trigger? I am struggling to decide among AfterUpdate, OnChange, OnExit. All three function the same in the context although they obviously have different functions.

Comment: After Update is the right event for this, but you should call the procedure from the event, eg `Sub IsThisOkay` :) You need to call the procedure from both Q1 and Q2, in case someone changes something. You will need to blank Q3 and Q4 if the two answers do not match your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Update is the right event for this, but you should call the procedure from the event, for example

```
 Sub IsThisOkay()
    ''Various checks
    ''If it is okay, Q3 & Q4 = -99
    ''Else Q3 & Q4 = Null
 End Sub

 Private Sub Q1_AfterUpdate()
    IsThisOkay
 End Sub

 Private Sub Q2_AfterUpdate()
    IsThisOkay
 End Sub
```

You need to call the procedure from both Q1 and Q2, in case someone changes something. You will need to blank Q3 and Q4 if the two answers do not match your criteria.

Comment: Great advice, thanks! And yes, I have built in the return to Null of the skipped questions in case Q1 and Q2 have changed. Hope this thread helps others.